# ext4 mount options on Android

Tags: android, mount, ext4

The ext4 mount options for /data/ partition on Nexus 4 is data=ordered. Is the mount option for /data/ the same for all Android devices (Galaxy s4, Nexus, HTC) i.e. is it OEM-independent and does Google dictate the terms for it or is it left to OEMs to configure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i think it must be OEM independant cause mount is provided by os not by OEM.

Answer (score 0):

This option has three possible values: journal,ordered,writeback

journal is ​​the safest, 
writeback has the best performance,
ordered is default and balanced.

Phone is a mobile device, which power supply is battery. 
Manufactuers must take care of both data safety and performance, so i think 'data=ordered' is their best choice.

As i know, samsung, htc, nexus etc. all use this mount option.